# Check whether a record in DB with same ID has different value in field

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I would like to check whether a record with the same ID (Product_ID) has more than one record with a different date (I would like to check if the product was received in different loots or in just one day), so if it just returns one row it means that it was delivered all the same day, and if more than one result is return its the other way round.

**Table PRODUCT**

```
ID (PK) | Product_ID | Type | Deliver_Date | Amount
```

I've tried with a group by and distinct with no result.

***EDIT***: Query I had so far...

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ,
                count(*)
FROM            PUBLIC.product
WHERE           product_id = ?
AND             deliver_date = ?
HAVING          count() = 1
```

Comment: Well, *what* did you try with group by and distinct?

Comment: @RealSkeptic sorry for the late reply... the query I had was "select distinct *, count(*) from public.product where product_id = ? and deliver_date = ? having count(*) = 1" trying to retrieve all the rows which product_id just had one value for the deliver_date, and "count(*) > 1" for those with more than one date... But it seems to be not working properly I don't know why...

Comment: Never put code in the comments. Edit the question and add the code to it. You can then use a comment to alert someone to the fact that you made a change.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Updated, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of the `DISTINCT` keyword is incorrect.

You can either use `DISTINCT` with a list of fields following it, telling which fields you want to have distinct, or use an aggregate function like `COUNT`, `SUM`, `MIN` etc. together with grouping fields.

E.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product_Id, Deliver_date
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

means "give me all the distinct combinations of product id and deliver date". This is not actually what you need, as `DISTINCT Product_id` will simply tell you which product IDs there are, but not how many of them and in which dates, and `DISTINCT Product_id, Deliver_date` will give you all possible combinations of product ID and deliver date, but you'll need to count them manually.

The `GROUP BY` construct is more informative

```
SELECT count(*), Product_Id
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY Product_Id
```

Groups the rows by the product id. It tells you how many rows are there for each product ID.

But what if you have several rows with the same product ID and the same date? You'll get a number greater than 1 in that query, but it won't help you because you wanted to distinguish between products delivered on two different days and products delivered all on the same day.

To do this, you need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT(Deliver_date))`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Deliver_date)), Product_ID
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY Product_ID
```

This means:
  * Separate the rows into groups by the `Product_ID`.
  * Inside each such group (all the rows that have that `Product_ID`), find all the distinct `Deliver_Date` values. Count how many such `Delivery_Date` values there are inside the group.

So if the product was delivered 10 times within the same day, you'll just have one distinct delivery date for that product ID. The `COUNT` will return 1. If it was delivered 5 times on day x, and 5 times on day y, then you'll have *two* distinct delivery dates (x and y), and the COUNT will return 2.

Now, if you want to eliminate all the ones that were all delivered on the same day (the count of distinct dates is 1), you add a `HAVING` clause to your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Deliver_date)), Product_Id
FROM PRODUCT
GROUP BY Product_Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(Deliver_date)) > 1
```

This will give you a list of all the products that were delivered on at least two separate dates.

Of course, if you just want to check if a particular product was delivered on more than one date, it's simpler:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Deliver_date))
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE Product_ID = ?
```

This will give you the number of distinct days on which this product was delivered. If it delivered on just one day, the result will be 1. If it was delivered on more than one day, the result will be a number greater than one.

---

To sum up:

- There is no such thing as a `DISTINCT,`. `DISTINCT` is always followed by the name of a field or fields that are supposed to be distinct.
- But there is a `COUNT(DISTINCT(field_name))` which counts how many distinct values the field has in a group or a result set.

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. Writing `DISTINCT(field_name)` makes no sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I admit that I don't know what HSQL does, my experience is more in PostgreSQL. Now, in PostgreSQL, if you have more than one field in the `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT`, it thinks that you are using a two-argument `COUNT` function, that doesn't exist. So you need to write `COUNT(DISTINCT(a,b))` rather than `COUNT(DISTINCT a,b)`. So I just always use parentheses.

Comment: `(a,b)` is not the same as `a,b` in Postgres `(a,b)` creates an anonymous "record type" - a single column with two fields. It's a short version of [`row(a,b)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS). Because of that `count(distinct(a,b))` _happens_ to work in Postgres - you are still counting a single "column expression". I won't work in any other DBMS. It's still `count(distinct some_expression)` where `some_expression` happens to be `(a,b)`. Writing `distinct(..)` as a function call is simply wrong.

Comment: I checked it and it works in hsql-db, with or without parentheses. Including `COUNT( DISTINCT a,b )` and `COUNT( DISTINCT (a,b))`. Apparently, different vendors have different ideas about SQL syntax. So it's not a function. But it's also not wrong.

Comment: HSQLDB accepts COUNT( DISTINCT a,b ) as it is Standard SQL. The DISTINCT (a,b) form is counting distinct rows from a row constructor and gives the same result.

Comment: @fredt: thanks, I tried `count(distinct a,b)` on Oracle, SQL Server and DB2 (neither accepts that) and the SQL standard only defines `count(<value_expression>)` and I couldn't find an indicator that `<value expression>` is allowed to be more than one value/column - it _does_ allow `<value expression>` to be a `<row value expression>` though, which is the `(a,b)`  syntax.